# Removing the single quotes when printing string?

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I am trying to send variables to Zingharts to set background colors.

This is the format I need to create to set the backgrounds.

```
"styles":[
      { 
        "background-color":"pink",
        },
      {  
        "background-color":"red",
        },
      { 
        "background-color":"green",
      },
    ]
```

I created the string with python and then print it out in the chart:

```
'marker'    : {
                "styles":  var-background,
              },
```

This is the result I get.  You will see I get the extra ' at the start and end.  This prevents the code from working.

```
'styles': ' [{"background-color":"#C2D3EC" },
            {"background-color":"#52702A" },
            {"background-color":"#C2D3EC" },
            {"background-color":"#82B6FF" },
            {"background-color":"#52702A" }
            ] '
```

How can I print the var-background string without the beginning and ending single quote marks?

Thank you.

Comment: Without knowing the current code, it is very hard to say how it could be fixed...

Comment: You are passing this as a string instead of an array of dictionary. Post code where you are making this styles string

Comment: yes it is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json

d = {'styles': ' [
        {"background-color":"#C2D3EC" },
        {"background-color":"#52702A" },
        {"background-color":"#C2D3EC" },
        {"background-color":"#82B6FF" },
        {"background-color":"#52702A" }
        ] '
    }

d['styles'] = jason.loads(d['styles'])
```

the `json.loads` will convert a json string to a json object.

Comment: I was thinking I had to go json? I did get a list to work which I sort of based on your code.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the follow to work by switching from a string to a list.

```
var-background = [ ]

for index, row in df.iterrows ():
    var-background.append ( { 'background-color': row.color } )
```

Thanks.